# How to pass parameter into super class?

Tags: java, android

I am trying Custom  ListView Example. It's code is as follows,

// Adapter

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web; 
    private final Integer[] imageId;

    public CustomList ( Activity context, String[] web, Integer[] imageId )
    {
        super ( context, R.layout.list_single, web );
        this.context = context; 
        this.web = web; 
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView ( int position, View view, ViewGroup parent )
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.list_single, null, true );

        TextView txtTitle = ( TextView ) rowView.findViewById( R.id.txt ); 
        ImageView imageView = ( ImageView ) rowView.findViewById( R.id.img );
        txtTitle.setText( web[position] );
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position] );
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

// Activity File

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    ListView list; 
    String[] web = { "Google Plus","Twitter","Windows","Bing","iTunes","WordPress","Drupal" };
    Integer[] imageId = { R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image4,R.drawable.image5,R.drawable.image6,R.drawable.image7 }; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        CustomList adapter = new CustomList ( MainActivity.this, web, imageId );
        list = ( ListView ) findViewById( R.id.list );
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Consider following line in the Activity code,

`CustomList adapter = new CustomList ( MainActivity.this, web, imageId );`

Now I do not want to pass those array parameters into Adapter code then What changes I need to do in Adapter code ?

I try my self as follows in Adapter,

```
    String[] web = { "Google Plus","Twitter","Windows","Bing","iTunes","WordPress","Drupal" };
    public CustomList ( Activity context )
    {
        super ( context, R.layout.list_single, web ); // error at this line
        this.context = context; 
    }
```

But it is giving me compile time error `cannot refer to an instance field web while explicitly invoking a constructor`.

Comment: Sidenote: You don't have to hold a reference to the context by yourself. The superclass already does. Use getContext().

Comment: @isnot2bad what ? I didnt get you.

Comment: You don't need private final Activity context in CustomList as the super class already holds a reference to the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line to

```
private static final String[] web = new String[] { "Google Plus","Twitter","Windows","Bing","iTunes","WordPress","Drupal" };
```

and it should work.